# Resizing grid by client screen size

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, client, screen

I want to set datagrid's size at page load by client screen size. Is there any way to get this size at page load or other page events on server side?

I use `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth` and `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight` but these sizes is not true. these sizes is always 640 * 480.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use percentage sizes? Try and set the width height to percentages and see if it resizes when you resize the browser window.

Comment: @mortb: it is not possible;

Answer (score 1):

`Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth` and `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight` cant give client screen resolution on server side.

The best way to get this is using javascript-

```
<%if (!this.IsPostBack)
{%>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var rowURL = window.location.href;
var screenWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
if (rowURL.indexOf("screen_width") == -1)
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?screen_width=" + screenWidth;
</script>
<%}%>
```

Use this script in 'body' tag of the page. 
It just appends the 'screen_width' parameter to query string and refreshes the page. 
In this way you can get the value of the 'screen_width' on server side from query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to get the viewport width and height. Then pass the values back via a hidden form input or ajax.

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

First, add these hidden form inputs to store the width and height until postback.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="width" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="height" runat="server" />
```

Next we want to get the window (viewport) width and height. JQuery has two methods for this, aptly named width() and height().

Add the following code to your .aspx file within the head element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#width").val() = $(window).width();
    $("#height").val() = $(window).height();    

});
</script>
```

This will result in the width and height of the browser window being available on postback. Just access the hidden form inputs like this:

```
var TheBrowserWidth = width.Value;
var TheBrowserHeight = height.Value;
```

I hope it might be helps you....

Comment: I need these sizes in one of the page's events, but your solution is not suitable for me.

Comment: Do you need to resize in clientside or server side event?

Comment: I need to resize in server size.

Comment: if you want you can access hidden field value on server side.

Comment: I need these values on page_load but your solution get values after that.